# How do I make defuse kits purchasable without making it competitive?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I want to play on de_lake or any of the other wingman maps with competitive mode on but everytime I try play them and use game_type 1 it changes it to arms race. Is there any way to either do the commands for competititve (free armour, friendly fire and defuse kits purchasable) or make it competitive?

Comment: As for the friendly fire, use mp_friendlyfire 1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about friendly fire but if you play casual you should automatically have a defuse kit already purchased.

If you must have them purchasable, why not just select a competitve match? You can customize it as much as you would like and also set it so that no one else can join. There is no reason to limit yourself to casual if a switch to comp will literally get rid of all your problems.

Here is a link I found with some useful info: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=477696626

Comment: I know how to set up a competitive match, but I want to have armour for free, but defuse kits purchasable.

Answer (score 0):

Type in the console:

```
mp_defuser_allocation "0"
```